# Proof: $a<b$ and $ b<c$, then also $a<c$ (for partially ordered set of $M$)

Tags: linear-algebra, order-theory

I have the following question:

If $\leq$ is a partially ordered set over $M$ and $a<b$ and $b<c$, then also $a<c$ holds.

I'm a little confused, because I know that a partially ordered set is a transitive relation and that's exactly the statement from above. Did I miss anything and if I did, perhaps someone can help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't quite follow from definition because you must prove that $a \ne c$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you define $a<b$ whenever $a\leq b\wedge a\neq b$. Then use the fact that $\leq$ is a partial order, thus it is *transitive*, and the additional hypothesis that $a\neq b$,$b\neq c$ to conclude.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; Am I right, that $a \leq b,b \leq c \Rightarrow a \leq c$ is the definition of partial order and I only have to figure out, how to get $a \neq c$ from $a \neq b, b \neq c$ without transitivity?

Comment: @ulead86 Yes. Note that you know that $a\neq b$, and $b\neq c$. What if $a=c$? Use antisymmetry to reach a contradiction.

Comment: Something like: I know $a \neq b, b \neq c$. I suppose $a=c$, then follows from antisymmetry $b=c$, which is the necessary contradiction?

Comment: @ulead86 Yes, perfect. Note it *also* follows $a=b$.

Comment: $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a \Rightarrow a=b=c$, which is a contradiction to $b \neq c$? Thanks a lot for you patience.

Comment: @ulead86 You're welcome.